# Iterating over a list in file.txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, text-files

I’m trying to create a simple program where the user can enter their name, available weekday and time during those days and based on the appointments in the data.txt file append their name to the list.

The error is :

```
Exception has occurred: UnsupportedOperation
not readable( When the program read's the lines in data_file.
```

```
data.txt = [["Dinner", "Friday", "2000"], []]
           [["Workout", "Sunday", "1200"], []]


def Make_Apointment(person_name, available_day, available_time):
        data_file = open("data.txt","a")

        for line in data_file.readlines():
            if line[0][1] in available_day and available_time in line[0][2]:
                line[1].write(person_ name)
```

Comment: You are opening the file for appending `'a'` but then you try to read it.  Try with `'a+'` instead. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open

Comment: It looks like you are trying to store structured data in a file - you probably want to think about using `json` or `yaml` instead.

Comment: Or refactor the file to be a simple CSV file if it's a regular matrix with the same number of fields on every row.

Comment: Your mental model of text files is probably incorrect. You can't write to a line you already read; the next write will overwrite the remainder of the file, not just the current line. If you want random access (i.e. being able to zip back and forth and write things to different places in the structure), perhaps use a simple database instead.

Comment: Opening a file in append mode positions the cursor at the end of the file, where there is nothing left to read. You may want to open the file in read-only mode first, read its contents into memory, then open it in append mode while iterating over the pre-read list.

Comment: I appreciate all the answers! Found changing everything to json being the best solution!